# NoneType object has no attribute to get (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know why this is not working and it is really annoying,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def do(r, a):
    s = r.get()
    p = a.get()
Button(root, text="DEL3TE", fg="red", command=lambda: do(r, a)).grid(row=0, column=0)
r = Entry(root, width=15, bg="white").grid(row=0, column=1)
a = Entry(root, width=15, bg="white").grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(text="text1").grid(row=1, column=2)
Label(text="text2").grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(text="You have obtained the death note", fg="red").grid(row=2, column=0)
mainloop()
```

The error code is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anglc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/anglc/Desktop/test.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    Button(root, text="DEL3TE", fg="red", command=lambda: do(r, a)).grid(row=0, column=0)
  File "C:/Users/anglc/Desktop/test.py", line 5, in do
    s = r.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I can't figure out how to fix it, please help, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are making an entry, be sure that it is not formatted like this:

```
r = Entry(root, width=15, bg="white").grid(row=0, column=1)
```

It should be like this to remove an AttributeError:

```
r = Entry(root, width=15, bg="white")
r.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line :
Button(root, text="DEL3TE", fg="red", command=lambda: do(r, a)).grid(row=0, column=0)

After lambda you need to give :

Button(root, text="DEL3TE", fg="red", command=lambda r,a: do(r, a)).grid(row=0, column=0)

As you the do function only get the None value that you have need to pass real value you the do function.

Comment: This gives me a new error, <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'r' and 'a' its a TypeError btw

Comment: you have to first assign values to r and a and then call the function do.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def do(r, a):
    s = r.get()
    p = a.get()
r = Entry(root, width=15, bg="white").grid(row=0, column=1)
a = Entry(root, width=15, bg="white").grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(root, text="DEL3TE", fg="red", command=lambda r,a: do(r, a)).grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(text="text1").grid(row=1, column=2)
Label(text="text2").grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(text="You have obtained the death note", fg="red").grid(row=2, column=0)
mainloop()

Comment: whats the error

Comment: That doesnt work for me and it defines r and a before

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anglc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'r' and 'a'

Comment: I was able to fix it on my own, thanks though!